# Writing list to csv in Python 3.5

Tags: python, list, csv

I am trying to write

```
a = [0,1,0,1,1,0]
```

to a csv file, with

```
with open("output.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(a)
```

and I get

```
Error: iterable expected, not int
```

from the last line. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you expect your csv to look like? the argument to `writerows` should be an iterable of iterables, like a list of lists, where each sublist is a row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`writerows` expects an iterable of iterables for writing multiple rows at a time, but your list contains integers, which are certainly not iterable.

What you want is `writerow`:

```
writer.writerow(a)
```